# What are files with ".des" extension? how can i edit or change them?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I had previously also asked a question on this and was unable to get any concrete reply. I hope this time you guys will help me out.I have graphics files with ".des" extension when I open them in xcode I just see a long number or probably a hash code 1245.5678.2457.3578... like this. Now I want to be able to see these ".des" files in form of image in some software so that I can change them.
I have tried **coreldraw** and **interscope blackbox** but it did not work for me.Looking forward to hear from  you guys.

Comment: Is Googling ".des extension" really that difficult? Take a look [here](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/des).

Comment: What does this have to do with iPhone?

Comment: he has in his answer that he has opened in coreldraw...please don't comment out useless info..you just pointed him again to open in coreldraw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DES File: What they are and how to create them**

In Open GL ES (this is the name of the low level library for drawing 2d or 3d graphics on your iPhone) you can properly load images only in a specific size - this size is called the “power of two” (read more)

EXAMPLE: 512pixels x 512pixels = 29 pixels x 29 pixels or 1024 x 1024 = 210 x 210

But in real life is really hard to keep all your graphics materials in power of two sizes (POT). In modern OpenGL versions you can find a way to load non-POT images but this is not effective and will eat more memory while holding your textures.

To solve this issue you can put all you small images in to one really big image (sometimes called a resource image, atlas, sprite sheet, sprite list, etc). We call this an Atlas.

So what does DES mean?

A DES file is very tiny plain text file. In this file you can find information about the atlas file including: where to find atlas (resource) image AND describe the position of original image on atlas image.

Basically, this DES file tells us where certain images are in the big ATLAS image.
As example if you have a folder called MainMenu and two files button.png and levelIcon.png after atlas making process you’ll have two DES files button.des and levelIcon.des and two big images MainMenu.png and MainMenu_hi.png ( *_hi.png is for Retina Displays and IPad )

Comment: Thanks for your explanation it is really helpful.I have just one point left here that is unanswered.Can you please describe how I can make this atlas for example how can i make button.des from button.png? Just describe the atlas making process please so that I am able to make the .des files myself.

Comment: i don't have much experience in creating them and software required..since these practice has been replaced by TexturePacker in cocos2d....i will suggest to ask this question in open gl section...and do accept my answer.. :)

Comment: I asked this question in opengl section still they find it off topic I have also put it on various or forums but still not result is there anything you can help me with?

Comment: @hariszaman
have you got the solution?how I can make this atlas for example how can i make button.des from button.png? Just describe the atlas making process

Comment: Yes, I have a python script that actually makes the atlases pngs and there .des file from the images